# For Server validation using a trusted CA, will the ca-public key that was used to sign the server certificate be provided back to the server?

Tags: server, openssl, self-signed, ca

I was working on a sample TLS client/server program to perform certificate validation.

For a self signed certificate validation, these are the steps i followed.

@server side:

1. Generated a server key file serverkey.key
2. Generated a CSR certificate servercert.csr from the key file.
3. Digitally signed(using openssl x509 utility) the servercert.csr using a 
   generated rootCA.key and rootCA.cert. server certificate file servercert.cert 
   is generated.
4. Loaded the certificate file(servercert.cert) and key file(serverkey.key) using 
   `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey` openssl apis.

@client side:

1. Loaded the server ca-file --> rootCA.cert (which was manually copied to the 
   client) using the `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` api.
2. Using the `SSL_get_verify_result`() api validated the certificate that server 
   sends in the Certificate message.

The question that i have is that if i use a trusted CA(like godaddy) to sign a server CSR certificate, will the CA be providing its public key file (something similar to rootCA.cert) as well which was used for signing ?
By which i can load the same to the trusted list at client side using `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` api.

My intention is to keep the code unchanged regardless of being a self signed certificate or a valid CA provided certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When (any) x509 certificate is generated, these things happen:

1. Private key is generated
2. Public key (associated with the private key mentioned above) is **embedded** in the new certificate (becomes an integral part of it)
3. The new certificate is signed using **private key of the issuer** (read: CA)

In order to verify the certificate integrity (to check if nobody tampered with it) - you need to verify the signature (created using issuer's private key - see **3)**). To be able to do it you need to obtain (somehow) the issuer's **public key**. This key **is embedded in the issuer's certificate** (see **2)**). Usually the trusted CAs' certificates are stored in so called *trusted certificate store*. In case of OpenSSL you specify this "store" by using `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` function (and a few other simmilar functions - consult OpenSSL documentation).

**To summarize:**
In your case the location pointed by `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` **should contain your CA's certificate(s)** - all of them - the whole certificate chain up to the self-signed root certificate. You can obtain all of the certificates in the chain from your CA (in your case GoDaddy).

I hope that helps.
If I can clarify anything more please ask.